# Can I apply a feather to clipping in aegisub?

Tags: subtitles

```
{\clip(187.2,187.2,1084.8,700.8)}Like falling in love or getting your heart broken.
```

Is there a way to apply a more gradual fade (a feathering effect) when clipping your subtitles with the clip commands? I haven't been able to find anything. I know there's iclip, which lets you invert the clipping area...there are drawing tools to make a more distinct clip area like bezier or whatever included in the gui...but that's like it I can find.

I'm going to be really surprised if this doesn't exist somewhere for this program. Anyone see any examples of usage that include this effect? The only way I can think of is an image overlay that includes faded edges that would function as a fade for the underlying text.